# Can't Minimize Video Track Timeline Zoom Automation

Tags: davinci-resolve

This is a simple problem that is driving me crazy. I must have accidentally hit some button that made the track height expand to show zoom automation data in the timeline. It looks like this.
[image]

Please show me how to make this disappear.
I am using Davinci Resolve 17 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two white squares to the right of the clip name in your image - those will close the curve and keyframe viewers, respectively.